# Can you use a search widget to search for text in android:text="______" fields?

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I'm building an app with linear and relative layouts to create lists. I want to have a search function to search through text fields and return the results with "links" to the pages it pulls the results from.

I don't know if I am explaining this well enough, but that's what I need help with. I can find all sorts of search help but it all seems to revert back to ListView's.

Answer (score 0):

You should aim to create your "lists" from some form of data-store. Usually a database, see [SQLite Databases in Android](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html). You should then use the query language to return only fields that match your search term e.g. "SELECT * FROM people WHERE name = 'Adam'".

To directly answer your question, the searching of text fields (EditText's or TextViews) is not possible to do automatically and you would need to hard code the search for each individual one.